# Fetching a subset of array in the prescribed order

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I have a master array and a query array:-

```
master_array=[2;5;3;7;1];
query_array=[1;3];
```

All elements of query array will be a member of the master array. That is a rule. I have to find the order of all the elements of query array as prescribed by the master array.

I could naively do this:-

```
a=[];
for i=query_array'
a=[a;i,find(master_array==i)];
end
a=sortrows(a,2);
order_array=a(:,1);
```

Is a more efficient solution available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html):

```
order_array = intersect(master_array, query_array, 'stable');
```

Or you could use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
order_array = master_array(ismember(master_array, query_array));
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution takes almost 70% less time in my benchmarks:

```
[~,idx] = ismember(master_array,query_array);
order_array = query_array(idx(idx > 0));
```

For more information about the `ismember` function, refer to [this page](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) of the official Matlab documentation.